# How do I solve an ambiguity conflict between two dissimilar operators using the same characters in bison

Tags: c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

The language I'm implementing has a conflict between the two operators `| * |` and `* || *` -- the first is a "norm" operator, where two `|`-characters surround an expression and the other is an or operator, where two expressions sandwich two `|`-characters.

So far I am able to parse expressions similar to `||| a || b | | |` -- i.e. three levels of norm around a single or (with any number of levels of norm and any series of or operators in the norms); this only works when the tail of the expression consists of `|`-characters which have whitespace between each other -- i.e. `||| a || b | | |` will work, but `||| a || b |||` will cause a syntax error. I want to be able to parse the last version as three norms with `a or b` inside.

Minimalistic version of my implementation (i.e. the relevant parts):

Bison/Yacc part:

```
%token NUM
%token OR
%token NORM

%right LOR ROR 
%right NORM
%right OR
%right '|'

%%

expression:
    NUM
    | lnorm expression rnorm %prec NORM
    | expression LOR ROR expression %prec OR

lnorm: '|' | ROR | LOR
rnorm: '|' | LOR
```

Flex part:

```
%x NOR NOR2


%%
-?[0-9]+                  { return NUM; }
"|"                       { yy_push_state(NOR); }

<NOR2>.  { yyless(0); yy_pop_state(); return ROR; }
<NOR>"|" { BEGIN(NOR2); return LOR; }
<NOR>.   { yy_pop_state(); yyless(0); return '|'; }
```

I use the NOR and NOR2 states to make sure that an OR operator is only accepted if there is nothing between the |-characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start with, **your language is intrinsically ambiguous**. You can resolve the ambiguity in various ways -- there are some ideas below -- but such ambiguities are generally not a good idea, because they not only make the language hard for machines to parse; they make it hard for humans to parse. The world is full of computer languages with quirky parses and FAQs explaining why what you wrote didn't end up being what you meant.

(In the following, I'm going to use `⌈…⌋` instead of `|…|`for `norm`, and `x‖y` instead of `x||y` for `or`, in order to show how expressions parse.)

Here's a simple ambiguity:

```
|a|||b|||c|
```

It could be:

```
⌈a‖⌈b⌋‖c⌋
```

or

```
⌈a⌋‖b‖⌈c⌋
```

So we need to be able to choose one or the other of these two interpretations.

If we use the grammar in the post, we need to be able to reduce each `|` which is really a `⌋` to the non-terminal `rnorm`, and each `|` which is a `⌈` to `lnorm`. By the logic of `LR(1)` grammars [note 1], we need to make this decision based only on the input up to the token immediately following the `|`.

It's easy to see that the first `|` will always be a `⌈`, but the `|||` is a challenge. If we're going to choose `⌈a⌋‖b‖⌈c⌋` as the correct parse, we need to decide that as soon as we have read `|a||`. If instead our disambiguation rule will go for `⌈a‖⌈b⌋‖c⌋`, we can wait a little longer, but we still need to decide when we have read `|a|||b`.

But whichever way we go, we're going to have to turn some other unambiguous strings into syntax errors. Here are some strings, all of which start `|a|||b`, with their unambiguous parses:

```
|a|||b        ⇒ ⌈a⌋‖b
|a|||b||      ⇒ ⌈a‖⌈b⌋⌋
|a|||b||c     ⇒ ⌈a⌋‖b‖c
|a|||b|||c||| ⇒ ⌈a‖⌈b‖⌈c⌋⌋⌋
```

In short, we cannot decide by the time we see the `b`. In fact, we cannot, in general, decide until we've seen the entire input, so it won't help to use an `LR(k)` parser for some larger value of `K`, even if we could find one.

This dilemma is typical of "premature reduction"; in this case, we're reducing various tokens representing the input `|` to a single non-terminal `rnorm` in order to avoid having a huge number of very similar productions coping with the cartesian product of the choices. Shortcuts like this are usually discouraged, partly because they remove the possibility to use disambiguation by precedence and partly because they can turn an LR(1) grammar into LR(2) or worse. We could get easily get rid of `lnorm` and `rnorm` (at the cost of a much larger grammar), but in this case it won't help; even with the `rnorm` reduction, we will still need to reduce the norm-bracketed expression no later than when we see the token after the `|` which closes the norm. And, as above, we just do not have enough information to do that.

Apparently, we either have to abandon the idea of LR(1) parsing, or we need to reject some unambiguous expressions (two of the above four expressions, for example).

---

Let's pause here for **a small detour**. In a standard expression grammar containing parentheses (of various types) and binary operators, an expression must match the regular expression:

```
OPEN* TERM CLOSE* ( OPERATOR OPEN* TERM CLOSE* )*
```

where `TERM` is a name or constant literal, `OPEN` is an open parenthesis of some form and `CLOSE` is a close parenthesis of some form.

If there are prefix and/or postfix operators, then we could change `OPEN` to `(OPEN | PREFIX)` and `CLOSE` to `(CLOSE | POSTFIX)`. It won't change anything I'm about to say.

Not all strings which match the regular expression are in the expression language, but every string in the expression language must match the regular expression. To restrict it to correct expression strings, we need to also require that the parentheses match correctly, which cannot be expressed in a regular language. But that's not important either.

It's possible to rearrange the regular expression into:

```
OPEN* TERM ( CLOSE* OPERATOR OPEN* TERM )* CLOSE*
```

which makes it clear that anything which comes before the first `TERM` is an `OPEN`; anything which comes after the last term is a `CLOSE`, and any string which comes between two `TERM`s contains exactly one `OPERATOR`, possibly preceded by `OPEN`s and followed by `CLOSE`s.

In your language, bars (`|`) can be either `OPEN` or `CLOSE`, and two of them can be an `OPERATOR`. Is there any advantage to requiring that an operator be two bars? No; doubling the bar in no way helps disambiguate the parse. A string of consecutive bars in between two `TERM`s must contain exactly one operator; spelling the operator as `||` only means that the strings of consecutive bars must be one bar longer.

---

Now, **let's take a look at the scanner** rules in the question.

A first observation is that they don't really work. Or perhaps it's a second observation, because the first observation is that they seem way too complicated for what they are trying to accomplish. The alternation between states `NOR` and `NOR2` means that a sequence of `|`s is lexed into an alternation of `LOR` and `ROR` tokens. For example, the expression: `|1||||2|` will be lexed as <kbd>|</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>LOR</kbd><kbd>ROR</kbd><kbd>LOR</kbd><kbd>ROR</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>. But that's not going to allow the correct parse (`⌈1⌋‖⌈2⌋`) because the middle two `|` characters are tokenized into <kbd>ROR</kbd><kbd>LOR</kbd>, and therefore won't match the expression production:

```
expression LOR ROR expression
```

That's fixable, of course. We just need to add more productions to the parser. But, yuk!

But the goal is only to require that two bars can only be recognized as an "or" operator if they aren't separated by whitespace. It is not necessary to to work so hard. The following is sufficient:

```
[0-9]+   { return NUMBER; }
[|]/[|]  { return COMBINING_BAR; }
[|]      { return NON_COMBINING_BAR; }
```

(The second rule cannot apply if the first one does, because the first one comes first and therefore has priority, but mostly because flex actually considers the length of the rule including trailing context in deciding which is the longest match.)

---

That style of lexing does work, and it comes in useful for **a similar issue in parsing C++** and other languages which unfortunately borrowed its unfortunate overloading of `<` and `>`, which can be template brackets, comparison operators, or shift operators. Without some disambiguation rule, in the C++ expression which starts

`A<B<x>>…`

it's theoretically possible for the `>>` to be any of

- two close template brackets
- a close template bracket followed by a greater than operator
- a right-shift operator.

Before C++11, it was always a right-shift operator. Since C++11, it will be two close template brackets, while the `>>` in `B<x>>…` will be a close template bracket followed by a greater than operator.

The C++11 disambiguation is based on a simple rule: "if the `>` could close an unclosed open template bracket, then it is a close template bracket" (even if it is immediately followed by another `>`). If you think about it, that's the only rule which can survive the LR(1) argument above; it allows the parser to make the decision about which type of token the `>` is as early as possible. This can be implemented using a technique similar to the above. In a very simplified form:

```
template_specialization
     : TEMPLATE_NAME '<' template_arguments '>'
template_arguments
     : template_argument
     | template_arguments ',' template_argument
     ;
template_argument
     : type
     | expression_other_than_gt
     ;
expression
     : expression_other_than_gt
     | expression '>' expression
     | expression COMBINING_GT NON_COMBINING_GT expression
     /* I left out what is needed to handle >>=, but it is similar */
     ;
expression_other_than_gt
     : ID
     | CONSTANT
     | '(' expression ')'
     | expression '+' expression
     /* and so on, including <, <<, <<= but without >, >>, >>= */
     ;
```

The use of `expression_other_than_gt` seems a bit ugly, and it is natural to ask whether precedence declarations could be used instead. I'll discuss that a bit later, but for now I'll just note that even if it is possible to get the precedence declarations right, it's not easy to do and harder to do in a way which can be proven to work, while it's relatively easy to write out the productions as above.

That lets us parse C++ template expressions with an `LR(1)` parser (provided we can identify the names of the templates, an issue outside of the scope of this answer). But it has a the cost of turning some otherwise unambiguous expressions into syntax errors. For example, the completely unambiguous

```
TemplateClassA<x > y> anInstanceOfA;
```

must be written

```
TemplateClassA<(x > y)> anInstanceOfA;
```

in order to avoid the first `>` being interpreted as a close template bracket. While entirely arbitrary, this rule is at least easy to explain ("parenthesize comparisons and shifts if you use them as template arguments") and C++ programmers seem not to have problems with it, possibly because it rarely arises. (On the other hand, having to insert an extra space into `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` in order to avoid the `>>` being turned into an illegal right-shift token was considered a major wart.)

---

Fortunately, **we're not limited to LALR(1) any more.** These days, bison comes with the ability to use a `GLR` algorithm which can parse *any* unambiguous context-free grammar. Not only that, but it comes with some new GLR tools for dealing with (some) ambiguous context-free grammars, which is just what we need to solve this particular problem.

Unlike regular `LR` parsing, `GLR` parsing is designed to live with ambiguity. If it finds that two or more parses are possible at some point in the input, it simply tries all of them. Most of the time, some later input will eliminate all but one alternative, and the GLR parser then performs all the semantic actions and continues the parse.

Technically, the GLR algorithm allows the parser to return a (compressed) datastructure which contains all of the possible parse trees. However, the bison implementation does require that the ambiguities be resolved; if not, an error message is generated and the parse is terminated. The disambiguation task is simplified, though, because it only happens when it is strictly necessary; that is, when the parser can prove that an ambiguity really exists.

We still need to have a rule which lets us decide which of the possible parses is correct. Here, I'll use the rule "a `norm` expression must be as long as possible", which came out of a discussion in the comments.

To avoid confusion, I'm not going to attempt to use both styles of disambiguation. They don't mix very well, and it is easy enough to write out an expression grammar without resorting to precedence rules. For expository purposes, I use only three operators, one of which (`&&`) binds more tightly than `||`, and the other of which (`,`) binds less tightly. Because this is a GLR grammar, there is no problem with premature reductions so I've used grouping non-terminals to simplify the grammar. (In practice, the parser will be slightly faster without the extra reductions, but that might not matter as much as readability.)

The lexer is the simple lexer above, which classifies `|`s based on whether or not they are immediately followed by another `|`, with the addition of a couple of rules for the other terminals. Most of the bison file should look familiar:

```
%glr-parser
%debug

%token NUMBER IDENTIFIER
%token AND "&&"
%token COMBINING_BAR NON_COMBINING_BAR

%%
program: /* empty */ | expression '\n' program;

bar: COMBINING_BAR | NON_COMBINING_BAR;
or:  COMBINING_BAR bar;

expression : alternation                 %dprec 2
           | expression ',' alternation  %dprec 1
           ;

alternation: conjunction                 %dprec 2
           | alternation or conjunction  %dprec 1
           ;

conjunction: term                        %dprec 2
           | conjunction "&&" term       %dprec 1
           ;

term       : IDENTIFIER
           | '(' expression ')'
           | bar expression bar
           ;
```

Aside from the `%glr-parser` declaration, the only difference is the pair of `%dprec` declarations in the various expression rules. `%dprec` (dynamic precision) is used to decide which of several possible reductions to the same non-terminal should be preferred when the parser has determined that more than one parse of that non-terminal is possible at the same point in the input. It chooses the parse headed by the reduction with the largest `%dprec`.

Note that this is *not* (usually) a reduce/reduce conflict. The reductions correspond to different parses resulting from some previous decision to accept, for example, both a shift and a reduce. Each reduction has its own parser stack, although after the reductions the parser stacks will be identical (that's necessary for the stacks -- parses -- to be merged). Within its own parser stack, each reduction is (usually) unconflicted.

In this particular case, we're trying to resolve the ambiguity which corresponds to the rule "choose the longest norm". If there is an ambiguity, the expression will start and end with a `|` and there will be one possibility where the starting and ending bars match, with other possibilities where they surround shorter expressions. We will want to select the production `bar expression bar`, which will bubble up through the unit productions; consequently, we give all the unit productions a higher merge precedence.

---

Alternatively, **we could try to use whitespace to disambiguate**, as you do by requiring that the operator `||` be written without an interior space. The ambiguity above could be resolved by this rule:

```
|a|| |b|||c| ⇒ ⌈a‖⌈b⌋‖c⌋
|a| ||b|||c| ⇒ ⌈a⌋‖b‖⌈c⌋
```

While that's unambiguous, it still falls short of being really readable. And this technique won't help with:

```
||||a| || || |b| || || |c||||
```

which could be `⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋‖⌈⌈⌈b⌋⌋⌋‖⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋` or `⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋⌋⌋‖⌈b⌋‖⌈⌈⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋`. The spaces only eliminate the otherwise possible `⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋⌋‖⌈⌈b⌋⌋‖⌈⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋`.

A different whitespace rule, similar to the one used in the ill-fated Fortress, would be to insist that:

- a left norm bracket must immediately precede the contained expression, without whitespace
- a right norm bracket must immediately follow the contained expression, without whitespace
- Two consecutive bars without intervening whitespace must either be two norm brackets or an operator.

(Remembering the regular language above, the last provision eliminates the possibility that two consecutive bars are different kinds of norm brackets; they must either both be opens or both be closes.)

With that rule, we end up with:

```
||||a| || |||b||| || |c|||| ⇒ ⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋‖⌈⌈⌈b⌋⌋⌋‖⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋
||||a|| || ||b|| || ||c|||| ⇒ ⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋⌋‖⌈⌈b⌋⌋‖⌈⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋
||||a||| || |b| || |||c|||| ⇒ ⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋⌋⌋‖⌈b⌋‖⌈⌈⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋
```

But, as noted above, the double bar doesn't really gain us anything. Simply requiring that `||` is always two norm brackets and never a norm bracket and an operator, we can go back to writing `or` as a single bar:

```
||||a| | |||b||| | |c|||| ⇒ ⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋‖⌈⌈⌈b⌋⌋⌋‖⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋
||||a|| | ||b|| | ||c|||| ⇒ ⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋⌋‖⌈⌈b⌋⌋‖⌈⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋
||||a||| | |b| | |||c|||| ⇒ ⌈⌈⌈⌈a⌋⌋⌋‖⌈b⌋‖⌈⌈⌈c⌋⌋⌋⌋
```

---

Finally, let's why **it can be hard to use precedence** to fix an ambiguous grammar.

Precedence declarations are great for simple expression grammars where we just need to define the binding power of different operators. They can also be used in a relatively understandable way to disambiguate "dangling-else" grammars. And they can sometimes be used for other grammar problems, but you need to be careful.

Precedence rules serve to resolve shift/reduce conflicts. If a production and a lookahead symbol have a defined precedence relationship and there is a shift/reduce conflict involving the production and the lookahead symbol -- that is, the grammar allows both the production to be reduced or the lookahead symbol to be shifted -- then bison will resolve the shift/reduce conflict by shifting if the lookahead symbol has higher precedence and otherwise reducing (associativity is taken into account in the comparison). Since it has used the precedence relationship to resolve the conflict, bison *does not* flag the conflict even as a warning. Moreover, if a precedence relationship is not actually used to resolve any conflict, bison also doesn't produce any warning. Once you use precedence declarations, you have signed away the right to be warned about many possible errors.

Non-trivial use of precedence declarations can have non-obvious effects on what language is really being parsed. In short, precedence is not a magic bullet; your feet still need some antiballistic protection.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no choice. Had I designed the language, I would have used 'or' instead of '||' -- likewise I would use 'and' instead of '&&' (the language is a lot bigger than this small portion, as I suppose you have guessed). I am quite familiar with the problems with >> in C++ -- I have tried to find out how gcc solves the problem but was unsuccessful. I generally try to avoid using %prec exactly because I am never entirely sure if it will work exactly the way it's supposed to or if it will mess up when I add to or change the parser. I felt obliged to use it in this though.

Comment: @Clearer: I really wouldn't use precedence for this problem, but it is possible that you can get it to work. However, you'll have to get rid of all shortcuts: you cannot get precedence to work meaningfully if you force premature reductions, as I indicated in the analysis of why your `lnorm` and `rnorm` non-terminals interfere with ambiguity resolution. I could write more on this theme, but not tonight, I'm afraid. My `>>` solution is not how gcc works -- gcc has a hand-written top-down parser -- but it is completely workable.

Comment: @Clearer: Also, if you have a disambiguation definition for your language, you should include it in your question. How do you expect |a|||b|||c| to be parsed, and why? Otherwise, it is impossible to provide any guidance about the best way to write the grammar.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get rid of the premature reduction; it's the cause of my problems, not part of the solution. I must be able to parse |a|||b|||c||| into (a||(b||(c))) (with '(' = lnorm, ')' = rnorm). As I tried to say before when I ran out of space, I'm only using %prec because that's the best I've been able to do; not using it causes to many other problems and, with a single caveat, it works the way it's supposed to (I believe).

Comment: @clearer: correct, you need to expand the terminals into the expression productions. And I repeat: is `|a|||b|||c|` parsed to `(a||(b)||c)` or to `(a)||b||(c)`? And why? What is the general rule? `|a|||b|||c|||` is not unambiguous, but it is useful to know that you require it to be parsed correctly. Look at my other examples starting `|a|||b`. Which of these do you require to be parsed as opposed to being a syntax error? (And, again, why? -- or rather, what is the rule behind your expectation?)

Comment: @Clearer: Anyway, it's 2:30 a.m. here, so I'll look at this in the morning... one more question: do you expect  |a||||b| to correctly parse to (a)||(b)? (If not, why not?). ... but that's a lexer issue, nothing to do with %prec.

Comment: 1) a new expression begins after an operator: +, -, *, /, or, and, prefix -, prefix !, <, >, <=, >=, !=, ==, after a | or (, any keyword which allow and expression immediately after it, on both sides of the = in an assignment statement 2) constants, variables and function calls are new expressions. 3) a new expression starting with a | character is a norm expression. 4) a norm expression ends as late as possible. 
|a|||b|||c| = (a||b||c)
|a|||b|||c||| = (a||(b||(c)))
|a|||b = (a) || b

Comment: I appreciate the help -- go get some sleep so I can abuse your expertise tonight (it's 10 in the morning here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54558/discussion-between-rici-and-clearer).

Comment: This is a tremendously useful respnse, and it shows the pitfalls of apparently simple combinations of grammatical rules.  It's a perfect example of what StackOverflow answers are meant to be.

Answer (score 1):

Without using flex for a pre syntax validation, with only the bison part (PIPE is the name of the final token |).

I guess the |.| operation is stronger in priority than .||. ?

Then, you can solve conflict by cutting your rules :

```
expr: expr_or

expr_or: expr_or PIPE PIPE expr_norm
    | expr_norm

expr_norm: PIPE expr_base PIPE
    | expr_base

expr_base: NUM | expr
```

Comment: I tried doing something like what you're proposing, but failed. Will try again. I've tried fiddling with the precedence of both operators, inserting precedence rules of the left and right side of both or and norm operators and, I believe, tried every permutation of precedence I could. BTW; there is no conflict according to bison -- it just doesn't produce the parser I want.